# How to separate the current AWS CloudFormation stack into multiple stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Currently, there is one big AWS CloudFormation stack that creates various resources like VPC, RDS, API Gateway, S3, Lambda, CloudWatch event rules, security groups, and ELB.

I wanted to implement database encryption as per the recommendation here https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-encrypt-aws-cloudformation-managed-rds-database-steve-kinsman/ I started working but was thinking it would be better to separate the RDS resource into its own stack.

Later this would also help me to implement a password rotation strategy and also any RDS upgrade in the future.

But I am stuck at a point since the resources like VPC and subnets are part of the original stack, should I move these also into the new stack where I want RDS?

Any recommendations?

In the existing stack I started by `DeletionPolicy: Retain` on the RDS resource, so that I detach the existing RDS from the existing stack.

But when I started creating the RDS in a new stack, I realized I also needed VPC details, so now I am unsure if will I need to create a new VPC or if I first need to remove it from the existing stack.